# Project upload error - G3W Suite

Tags: qgis, web-gis

After a lot of tries I succesfully installed G3WSuite - docker edition on a linode server.
I installed it with changind in the .env file only the hostname (I also tried one installation with the shared folder changed to /opt/./shared-volume).

After I log in and create the first group, I try to upload a project but I receive the following errors:

> [Project error on layers()]-- [Layer error on datasource(Arbori_noi_41ea6fd2_9639_4799_8d41_f3618e8c3784)]-- : Current datasource is /shared-volume/media/temp_uploads/Arbori_noi.gpkg|layername=Arbori_noi

Also when I try to upload the demo content, which is already optimized for the platform:

> [Project error on layers()]-- [Layer error on datasource(buildings_2f43dc1d_6725_42d2_a09b_dd446220104a)]-- : Current datasource is dbname='/shared-volume/project_data/spatialite/building_management_demo.sqlite' table="buildings" (geom)

I have tried to change the shared folder location from /root/g3wsuite-folder/shared-volume to /opt/./shared-volume but I still hit the same wall, so I don't think there is a permission issue.

Does anybody know how can I resolve this ?

Comment: I'm having the same error connecting to the database. Did you manage to solve it?